# Does MPEG-Dash live have ?begin parameter in their URI to start playback from a particular position

Tags: ffmpeg, media-player, mpeg-dash, mpeg

I have a MPEG-DASH URI like below

https://test.com/default/index.mpd?begin=20230222T120430

where i have begin parameter specifying from where to start the playback. This is a dynamic MPD.

I want to know is begin parameter a standard parameter of MPEG-DASH. If yes, then in which document this parameter is specified.

Comment: No, DASH is agnostic to the URL format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPEG-DASH is specified in ISO23009-1 - currently available at  https://www.iso.org/standard/83314.html - which is the document in which `begin` would be specified if it were part of the DASH specification.

Appendix C.4 lays out a couple of MPD anchors for use in starting the stream at a particular time, but `begin` is not one of them.

Note that many players will not implement these anchors even though they are in the specification.